# Why doesn't Python sqlite3 insert auto-incremented ID

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

In Python 3.4.1, why doesn't [sqlite3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html) insert the auto-incremented ID into the table in the below program? According to [the SQLite documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q1), an integer primary key column should auto-increment, and I can see that from cur.lastrowid returning a valid integer, BUT the same value is not inserted into the table (it becomes NULL instead).

```
import sqlite3


with sqlite3.connect(':memory:') as conn:
    cur = conn.cursor()
    # Note that column 'id' is an integer primary key
    cur.execute('create table test (id int primary key , name text)')
    cur.execute('insert into test (name) values (?)', ('Test',))
    last_id = cur.lastrowid
    assert last_id is not None

    id_, = cur.execute('select id from test').fetchone()
    assert id_ == last_id, '{} != {}'.format(id_, last_id)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, I was mistaken in thinking that 'int' is a synonym for 'integer' in SQLite. In fact, columns [are typeless in SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/datatypes.html) and `integer primary key` is an exception to this rule, declaring effectively an auto-incremented column:

```
import sqlite3


with sqlite3.connect(':memory:') as conn:
    cur = conn.cursor()
    # Note that column 'id' is an integer primary key
    cur.execute('create table test (id integer primary key , name text)')
    cur.execute('insert into test (name) values (?)', ('Test',))
    last_id = cur.lastrowid
    assert last_id is not None

    id_, = cur.execute('select id from test').fetchone()
    assert id_ == last_id, '{} != {}'.format(id_, last_id)
```

Comment: This is not a bug; the documentation clearly states you need to use `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY`.

Comment: The official type name is `INTEGER`, other names merely create a [type affinity](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html).

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yeah, you're right, I was able to dig up more information in the meantime. Wasn't aware of SQLite's typelessness until now. Thanks!